# Need to close PreparedStatements stored as SoftReference before its GC'd

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection

I am working with a in house DB Connection Pool which caches PreparedStatements. When the connection is returned to the pool, the cached Statements are not closed.  These create OutOfMemoryExceptions in mySQL driver. So I am planning to store the PreparedStatement cache in a HashMap <String, SoftReference<PreparedStatement>>

But this does not allow me to close the Statements before they are GC'd.

Using ReferenceQueue is of no use i guess, and I have read that finalize method is not advised.

Comment: What's the point of caching the PreparedStatements themselves, aside from leaking memory, and not the results?

Comment: Caching PreparedStatments does have it benefits, like saving one round trip to the database, every time they are used, but not sure the benefits outweigh the costs.. Anyways for me it would be much more complex to remove the caching (lots of performance testing) than the SoftReference approach I am suggesting.

Comment: Are you sure there's a round-trip to the DB when creating the PreparedStatement? I've never seen one, only on execution. Have you actually measured the supposed benefits when introducing these optimizations, in the global context of the application and not as a micro-benchmark? Is the creation of the PreparedStatements really a hotspot?

Comment: So let me summarize what you are saying.. invoking 100 prepareStatement(sql) has the same performance impact as doing a prepareStatement(sql) once and then for the next 99 times retrieving the statement from a client side cache?

Comment: @FrankPavageau On most databases there is a round trip on prepare.

Comment: I'm saying it could have a negligible impact, which would mean the development costs are not worth it. If the creation of the PreparedStatement only accounts for 1% of the global processing time, even making it 100 times faster only gets you .99 points of improvement. There are probably more interesting hotspots.

Comment: What makes you think a reference queue is of no use? And what made you choose SoftReference over WeakReference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be overriding finalize() could help?

Comment: I think, this is not good idea because that Java does not gurantee to call finalize() every time.

Comment: @ErdinçTaşkın It is guaranteed that GC occurs before an OutOfMemoryException, and GC requires prior finalisation.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Guava caches](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). You can use the `softValues()` method, a `RemovalListener` to close the `PreparedStatement` upon eviction.

Consider anyway if you really want to fill your memory with open `PreparedStatement`'s, or if you'd be better off by having a fixed cache size, and evicting the least recently used entries.

Comment: The RemovalListener only works if the value is evicted from the cache because of its policy, not because the GC needs the memory; otherwise it's the same problem as the ReferenceQueue, it's too late to close the statement. You also need an actively used cache for the listener to be called in a timely manner (hopefully that's the case here, or the cache is useless, but even then it's not guaranteed for all the Connections if the load is not constant).

Comment: Let me rephrase that: a PreparedStatement (or any object that needs closing) cache only works with an explicit eviction policy, not by using SoftReferences, that's the only way to get notified that the statement needs closing before it becomes unreferenced. With SoftReferences, you'll always get the notification too late through the ReferenceQueue, as the reference gets cleared during the GC run, when it decides it needs the memory, without the application ever regaining control in the middle.